# execute request in loop in order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following:

```
var request = require('request')
var j = request.jar()
var url1 = "www.google.com"
var url2 = "www.google.com/images"
request({url: url1,jar: j}, function() {
...
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
// list is just an item from a json response. 
// I need map the list[i] with the body into a JSON object. 
// But if I move the this to the request it get the last item and not each. 
console.log(list[i])
request({url: url2,jar: j}, function(err, response, body) {
          // This print after all the list[i] has printed 
          body = JSON.parse(body)
          console.log(body);
        });
}
});
```

I would like the JSON array to be something like

```
[{a: list[i], b: body}, {a: list[i], b: body}]
```

Question in the code comment. I'm no to javascript/node. I might not be understanding how things work.

Comment: There's a lot of code missing from this excerpt.  Not sure where some of the variables are declared etc.

Comment: I added more. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the value of `i` using a closure to preserve it in the callback:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
    (function(i) {

       request({ url: url2, jar: j }, function(err, response, body) {
           console.log(list[i]);
           body = JSON.parse(body);
           console.log(body);
       });

    })(i);
}
```

Comment: That helps. How do a push everything to a json array and then have that array outside of the closure?